# Returning results that start with a particular letter

Tags: php, mysql

The variable `$letter` is an English letter.

How can I put a `WHERE` clause on the query below so that it only returns results where `title` that start with the same letter as the variable `$letter`?

```
$letter = $_GET['letter'];

$query2 = "select title, COUNT(*) as titlerows from submission
GROUP BY title  
order by title asc
LIMIT $offset, $rowsperpage";
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$query2 = "select title, COUNT(*) as titlerows from submission WHERE title LIKE '$letter%'
GROUP BY title  
order by title asc
LIMIT $offset, $rowsperpage";
```

Edit:

```
$letter = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['letter']);

$query2 = "SELECT `title`, COUNT(*) as `titlerows` from `submission`
WHERE `title` LIKE '".$letter."%'  
GROUP BY `title` ASC  
LIMIT $offset, $rowsperpage";
```

Comment: As said on the other response. Letter should be escaped before going into a SQL statement. Or I could do `'; drop table submission; --` as letter in a manual get request

Comment: sorry i wrote that on the fly at my sisters real quick and just wrote the basics. update shoudl be good to roll out.

Answer (score 1):

```
WHERE `title` LIKE '$title%'
```

use LIKE then notice the %, it means none or all, this will return all records with title starting to the value of $title

Answer (score 0):

This should do it

```
$letter = $_GET['letter'];

$query2 = "SELECT title, COUNT(*) AS titlerows FROM submission WHERE title LIKE '$letter%'
GROUP BY title  
order by title asc
LIMIT $offset, $rowsperpage";
```

Comment: I would highly recommend that be fixed to properly escape the data before using it in a SQL statement or use a prepared statement.

Comment: @izuriel - yes, i agree with u, but the question where to put the WHERE clause

Answer (score 0):

First, you should never directly interpolate variables into a SQL statement unless you can be 100% sure that it is safe, i.e. you just defined it server side and it contains no data that the user could have made/changed. It's often best not to interpolate any variables into a query to be safe.

Second, as the other questions have provided the answer I will demo a safer version:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM submission WHERE title LIKE '" . mysql_real_escape_string($letter) . "%';";
```

The `%` character when used in a `WHERE ... LIKE ...` will match any number of characters, similar to `.*` in a regular expression. Also note that '_' can be used to match any single character.